# Values are getting changed in old pandas data frame when making changes in new pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

While executing the below code, the dataframe **x** values should not get changed as i am performing only for **y**

```
x = pd.DataFrame(data = {"test":["mkt1","mkt2","mkt3"],
                         "test2":["cty1","cty2","cty3"]})
y = x
y["test"] = "boom"
print(x)
```

Please see the output here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTz7W.png)

Comment: You should have read a of: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - else this will trip you up in Python in general.

Comment: This is normal.  Have a read of views vs copies https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/views_and_copies_in_pandas.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Riley . Problem is solved now :)